# Android application crashing without any visible error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

I am trying to create a University GPA Calculator App using Android Studio. 
Mainly this app has two `EditText` views which takes the "credit" and "grade" as input and displays it in a dynamically created `TextView` when the user clicks the "Okay" button.

I have defined lists which stores the values the user inputs in the `EditText` views. And call method to calculate the GPA, when "Calculate GPA" button is pressed.

The problem is that my application is crashing, but there is no visible error in the code or logcat.

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.parul.gpacalculator.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_credits"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Input Credits"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.048" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_grade"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/input_grade"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.188"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_okay"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/calculate_gpa"
            android:onClick="calcGpa"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>`
```

The logcat: [View Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwEqm.png)

Here is the java code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayout mLayout;
    private EditText mEditCreditText;
    private EditText mEditGradeText;
    private Button mButton;
    private int perSubjectPoint=0;
    private  int totalCredits=0;
    List<EditText> allCredits = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    List<EditText> allGrades = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
           mEditCreditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_credits);
           mEditGradeText =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_grade);
           mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
           mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());
           TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    }
    private View.OnClickListener onClick() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {          

                mLayout.addView( createNewTextView(mEditCreditText.getText().toString(), mEditGradeText.getText().toString()));

                allCredits.add(mEditCreditText);
                allGrades.add(mEditGradeText);
            }
        };
    }

    private TextView createNewTextView(String text1,String text2) {
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textView.setText("Credit: "+text1+ "\nGrade: "+ text2);
        return textView;
    }

    public int pointPerSubj(int number,String grade) {
        int point;
        if(grade.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
            point = 10;
        else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
            point = 9;
        else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
            point = 8;
        else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
            point = 7;
        else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
            point = 6;
        else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
            point = 5;
        else 
            point = 0;

        int perSubjectPoint = number * point;
        return perSubjectPoint;
    }

    public void calcGpa() {
        int size = allCredits.size();
        String[] stringsGrade = new String[size];
        Integer[] intCredits = new Integer[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            stringsGrade[i] = allGrades.get(i).getText().toString();
            intCredits[i] = Integer.parseInt(allCredits.get(i).getText().toString());
            totalCredits = totalCredits + intCredits[i];
            perSubjectPoint = perSubjectPoint + pointPerSubj(intCredits[i], stringsGrade[i]);
        }

        float gpa = perSubjectPoint/totalCredits;
        Toast.makeText(this,"Your GPA is: "+gpa, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Really does it crash? I've just looked at the Toast usage and you forgot to call `show()` on it (but this isn't crash)

Comment: Hi @Markaos, yes! it really crashes.

Comment: If it crashes, you should see some output. The error you get is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method calcGpa(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button2'`

Answer (score 0):

Your `calcGpa()` method is used as `onClick` attribute - the correct signature is `calcGpa(View v)`. If you do this, it will work